# Search KeePass for Password

Tags: keepass

I have a few hundreds of passwords in my KeePass database and I have structured them in groups. It seems that my way of thinking sometimes changes (e.g. I would add a VMWare password under IT/VMs now but I had it under OS/Virtual before).

It now happened that I remembered a password but neither the user name nor how I named the entry in KeePass. I'd like to find out if there's an entry in the KeePass database that uses this password, so I can find the user name and update the description.

I have tried: entering the password into the search box.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Use the Edit/Find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) feature
2. Turn on searching for passwords in the options

[image: KeePass Edit/Find]

[image: KeePass Find Password option]