# Search KeePassXC for password?

Tags: security, passwords

I got a weird spam/ransom email claiming that I've been compromised by the leak of a password that I definitely recognize as one that I have used (it is an 8 character random string, so they didn't just guess correctly).

The actual ransom note is not that compelling -- "I have used your password, `abc123` to hack your computer and now I have all your dirty photos which I will publish if you do not transfer US $819 into my bitcoin wallet immediately. I will also tell everyone about the piquant (you know what I mean) sites you have been visiting." -- but I'd like to double check that I'm not still using the password anywhere.

It has been a few years since I finally switched over to a password manager -- first KeePass, now KeePassXC -- and started using long, unique passwords and I'm reasonably confident this particular password is not still in use, but I'd like to be sure.

It looks like KeePass included a way to search for a password: 
[Search KeePass for Password](https://superuser.com/questions/1104500/search-keepass-for-password) but I don't see anything comparable in KeePassXC.

I could export the whole password database to a csv but that seems excessive and potentially dangerous.  Can I search my KeePassXC database for a particular password?

Comment: It's a common scam at the moment, try https://haveibeenpwned.com & see if you have a recognised leak. That may at least narrow it down.

Comment: You can open your KeePassXC database in KeePass and search for the password: it is the same database format. Otherwise, you can do as you say with exporting to CSV.

Comment: If you enable the option `Hide toolbar (icons)`, it also hides the search input field. It seems there's no other way to start a search from the UI apart from within the input field (unlike every other action in the toolbar). This is from v2.4.3, Windows.

Answer (score 5):

In KeePassXC it was [implemented with version 2.4](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/937) (currently in beta).

> In the upcoming v2.4 you can search for passwords using: password:[search string]. You can use wildcards and regex as well.

Alternatively you can [use KeePass](https://superuser.com/questions/1104500/search-keepass-for-password) in the meanwhile.